Totient equation
Find all natural numbers $n$ such that $\phi(n) = \frac{n}{2} - 8$.
I came up with this question myself, but I don’t know how to do it. I see that 48 works. Are there any other solutions?

Appears to be the odd primes times $16$.

Use the fact discovered by Robert, in conjunction with phi being multiplicative and it's product definition, from there I believe you get an always true equation

Your numbers are the odd primes times $16$.
If $n = 16 p$ where $p$ is an odd prime, then $\phi(n) = \phi(16) \phi(p) = 8 (p-1) = n/2 - 8$.
Conversely, suppose $\phi(n) = n/2 - 8$.  Let $n = 2^k r$ where $r$ is odd.
Then $\phi(n) = 2^{k-1} \phi(r) = 2^{k-1} r - 8$, so $\phi(r) = r - 2^{4-k}$.  $r = 1$ doesn't work because $\phi(1) = 1$.  For all other odd natural numbers $r$, $\phi(r)$ is even, so $2^{4-k}$ must be odd, i.e. $k = 4$.
Finally, $\phi(r) = r - 1$, and that implies $r$ is a prime.

Oh lol beat me by 4 minutes!
